# How to get location services to reprompt the user for location permission if they accidentally refused it?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, mkmapview, showuserlocation

When the users are asked to allow the user location, if they select accidentally "NO", then this alert is never shown in our app. Is there any option to reprompt the alert every time they open the app.After referring S.O question, many are suggesting this not all possible.Only thing can be do is, we have alert the user to turn-on location service in settings.

But in some S.O questions, starting `CLLocationManager` update method every time based on the user's selection we can reprompt the alert.Is it possible to achieve this?

Now my doubt is, is it possible to reprompt the alert when the user don't allow for the first time?

Please share your ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reprompt. You will have to UIAlert the user to go and do it manually.

Comment: Thank you. Even me too googled a lot to check , is there a way to enable it programmatically.But nothing found.But, are you sure it is not possible?

Comment: I use location services a lot in most of the apps I have written and never came across any way of a second prompt. I guess Apple does not want you annoying the user once No has been clicked. I would suggest a UIAlert to remind the user that your app only works if location services is enabled.